# Problema con ventana de opencv en python

Tags: python, opencv

Estoy creando un pequeño programa que detecta cosas con `haar cascades`, pero cuando se abre la ventana se queda en gris.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esté es el metodo que se encarga de la detección facial:

```
def detect(self, item):
    if not item in self.cascades:
        print("Cascade not found.")
        return 0
    detection = CascadeClassifier(self.cascades[item])
    cap = VideoCapture(0)
    while self.keepdetecting:
        ret, img = cap.read()
        gray = cvtColor(img, COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        detected = detection.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
        for (x,y,w,h) in detected:
            rectangle(img,(x,y), (x+w,y+h), (self.red,self.green,self.blue),2)
        imshow("Face detection", img)
    cap.release()
    destroyAllWindows()
```

y aquí está la clase entera:

```
class Detector:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cascades ={
        "Faces":"haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml"
        }
        self.keepdetecting = False
        self.red = 0
        self.green = 0
        self.blue = 255
    def detect(self, item):
        if not item in self.cascades:
            print("Cascade not found.")
            return 0
        detection = CascadeClassifier(self.cascades[item])
        cap = VideoCapture(0)
        while self.keepdetecting:
            ret, img = cap.read()
            gray = cvtColor(img, COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            detected = detection.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
            for (x,y,w,h) in detected:
                rectangle(img,(x,y), (x+w,y+h), (self.red,self.green,self.blue),2)
            imshow("Face detection", img)
        cap.release()
        destroyAllWindows()
    def shell(self):
        if pv()[0] == "3":
            raw_input = input
        if platform()[0] == "W":
            clear = "cls"
            costum_clear = clear
        else:
            clear = "clear"
            costum_clear = clear
        cmd = ""
        while cmd != "exit":
            cmd = raw_input(">>>")
            cmd, args = self.getcommandlist(cmd)
            if cmd == costum_clear:
                system(clear)
            elif cmd == "setcostumclear":
                costum_clear = " ".join(args)
            elif cmd == "detect":
                self.keepdetecting = True
                detect = Thread(target=self.detect, args=[args[0],])
                detect.daemon = True
                detect.start()
            elif cmd == "rgb":
                self.red = int(args[0])
                self.green = int(args[1])
                self.blue = int(args[2])
            elif cmd == "red":
                self.red = int(args[0])
            elif cmd == "green":
                self.green = int(args[0])
            elif cmd == "blue":
                self.blue = int(args[0])
            elif cmd == "stop":
                self.keepdetecting = False
    def getcommandlist(self, cmd):
        cmdlist = []
        for arg in cmd.split():
            cmdlist.append(arg)
        return (cmdlist[0], cmdlist[1:])
```

Me estoy basando en este programa:

```
from cv2 import *
import numpy as np

face_cascade = CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml")
cap = VideoCapture(0)
while True:
     ret, img = cap.read()
     gray = cvtColor(img, COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
     faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
     for(x,y,w,h) in faces:
     rectangle(img,(x,y), (x+w,y+h), (255,0,0),2)
     imshow("Face detection", img)
     if(waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("q")):
         break
cap.release()
destroyAllWindows()
```

Al ejecutar ese otro programa no se queda en gris la ventana ¿qué está pasando?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te falta agregar el **waitKey** del código original luego de usar **imshow**. 
En la documentación oficial de opencv,

https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=waitkey#imshow

verás que hay una nota al final de la función waitkey, que dice que cada vez que uses imshow, debes usar waitkey.

1.-Si no lo usas, la imagen capturada nunca se mostrará.

2.- Si usas waitkey(0), entonces se mostrará un fotograma, el cual quedará congelado, esperando a que presiones una tecla.

3.- Y si usas un valor *mayor a cero*, esperará ese tiempo luego de mostrar la imagen, y luego cerrará la ventana, para luego mostrar el siguiente fotograma del mismo modo, 
pero tu no notarás que esto sucede. La experiencia de usuario es que la ventana va actualizando su contenido.